# AsyncTask needs to long

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing, android-asynctask, threadpool

I have two asyncTasks which are dependend from each other. Task one has to wait till task two is finished. Because it is necessary to check the results of both, after it can continue. I execute the Threads with `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`. My information about this is that `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` executes the tasks parallel. 
At the end of task one I do the following to check the other variable as well:

```
if(!isCancelled())
{
    while(mOther.status)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(checkOtherNodeList(P)) // the results are that what it should be the tasks will be canceled 
    {
        mOther.cancel(true);
        nodesAddedToTrack.addAll(P);
        cancel(true);
        return null;
    }
    synchronized (mOther.status) {
        mOther.status = true;
    }
}
```

In Thread two I do at the end the following:

```
if(isCancelled())
{
nodesAddedToTrack.addAll(P);
    nodesAddedToTrack.add(T.get(nodenrfromP));
}
synchronized (status) 
{
status = false;
}
while(!status)
{
if(isCancelled())
    {
    nodesAddedToTrack.addAll(P);
    nodesAddedToTrack.add(T.get(nodenrfromP));
    return null;
}
}
```

The method checkOtherNodeList(P) is working with synchronization as well, because otherwise I would get a problem with the access on the two ArrayLists containing the results. 
The problem is that this parallelization lasts 3-5 times longer than I would run the program only in one task. Is that normal? Is the synchronization the problem?
Both Tasks are running in a while loop. At each run through of the while loop the Task one should compare the results. If they are that what I want both tasks will be canceled, otherwise both will run through another time and so on.

Comment: Why don't you simply start task two in onPostExecute() of task one?

Comment: Because that's not that what I need. If I would do that the parallelization wouldn't make sense. Thread one is running in a while loop actually. At the end of the first run it stop and wait for task two. If task two is finished task one will compare the results. If they fit it will continue both, otherwise it will cancel both tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some kind of status object with 2 booleans and pass it to both AsyncTasks. When the AsyncTasks finish let each change 1 boolean. In a setter you can discover whether the other boolean is already changed. In that case you can go on.